# How to focus on first input of error in js where return false is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have multiple input fields and if three fields showing error then focus goes on the last error field.
How to set focus on the first error field and so on. I tried `return false;` and it is not working. `preventDefault()` also not working.

This is my js code for the name field and the rest of the field validation is the same as this name field except validation rules.

```
if (name.length < 1) {
    $('#name_error').text(NAME_ERROR);
    $('#name').focus();
    error = true;
    // return false; not working
} else {
    var regEx = /^[A-Za-z ]+$/;
    var validName = regEx.test(name);
    if (!validName) {
        $('#name_error').text(INVALID_NAME_ERROR);
        $('#name').focus();
        error = true;
        // return false; not working
    } else {
        $('#name_error').text('');
        error = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- **Option 1** - Add class to the fields with error and then you can use below code to focus the first error element.

  ```
  $('.error-class').first().focus()
  ```
- **Option 2** - Create a variable of top of the function and store the ID of the first error field in that. At the end of the validation rules trigger focus for the element ID stored in a variable.